# ChatGPT: How to use long texts of unknown content in a prompt?

Tags: token, chatbot, tokenize, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I like the website [chatpdf.com](https://www.chatpdf.com) a lot. You can upload a PDF file and then discuss the textual content of the file with the file "itself". It uses ChatGPT.

I would like to program something similar. But I wonder how to use the content of long PDF files in a ChatGPT prompt, as ChatGPT only accepts 4096 tokens per conversation.

How can I reduce the number of tokens needed?

Important to consider is, that it is unknown, which documents will be used with this. Ant the goal is not to summarize the documents, but to have an in detail conversation about the content.

I tested it with an 56 pages PDF file with 11110 words. I tried to delete less important words from the string to feed into the prompt. But it only lead to an decrease from 27082 to 25288 tokens, according to OpenAI’s tiktoken library. Trying to mask these words with an [UNK] tag lead to an increase to more then 30000 tokens.

Comment: @KJ The ban applies to ChatGPT generated content, not to ChatGPT related questions.

Comment: @KJ, show me, where the ban says it applies to ChatGPT related questions and not only to ChatGPT generated answers. If you can’t, it doesn’t apply. Simple as that.

Comment: @KJ, yeah, but I am not using ChatGPT output. Nothing in my question is ChatGPT generated, it’s only ChatGPT related. And you are not able to show me a valid rule, that this isn’t allowed. The only source you provided is only about ChatGPT generated content.

Answer (score 1):

As Benevos said, you are limited to the model max token size (combined prompt and completion).  So for the gpt-3.5-turbo-0301 model it's 4096. i.e. for a prompt of 4000 tokens, it will give you back a maximum of 96 token response.

There are two options I have found to do what you want:

1. [fine-tune modeling](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning)
2. [Question Answering using Embeddings](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Question_answering_using_embeddings.ipynb)

Fine tune modelling requires a lot of data manipulation to get it right. So I don't recommend that way.

I would recommand OpenAI cookbook Question Answering using Embeddings example way of generating answers from your own private body of data.

I have created examples that take a pdf documents and does the "Question Answering using Embeddings" way and it's working ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if 4096 tokens is the limit you should adapt to that. You just can't reduce a big amount of words without losing the main idea of the document, or at least I don't know any method to do it.

What I suggest is to send multiple documents to the AI of maximun of 4096 tokens to analyze individually and discuss on every file.